# Error while getting a JsonObject from a string

Tags: json, xamarin.android

I am struggling with that issue for a quite long time.
In fact, I have a QR Code in which I have this text:

```
{ "Version ":  0x1, "Type ": "MapPoint ",  "X ": 2, "Y ": 3}
```

Then I transform the content of this QR code to a Json Object:

```
JSONObject scanQRCode = new JSONObject(contents);
```

When I debug, I find that the string contents is like that:

```
" { \"Version \":  0x1, \"Type \": \"MapPoint \",  \"X \": 2, \"Y \": 3} "
```

And ScanQRCode equals to that:

```
    {{"Version ":1,"Type ":"MapPoint ","X ":2,"Y ":3}}  Org.Json.JSONObject
```

And the in my code I have to verify this condition and get the double X and Y as following:

```
     if (scanQRCode.Has("Version") && scanQRCode.GetInt("Version") >= 0x1 && scanQRCode.Has(KEY_QR_TYPE) && scanQRCode.GetString("Type").Equals(("MapPoint")))
 {
 float x = (float)scanQRCode.GetDouble("X");
  float y = (float)scanQRCode.GetDouble("Y");
}
```

the problem is that condition is never fulfilled and I can't even get for example the double X.

Can you please tell me what is wrong?

Answer (score 0):

```
{ "Version":  "0x1", "Type":"MapPoint",  "X": 2, "Y": 3}
```

This is already a json object no need to convert it again you can directly use it as follow

```
var a = { "Version":  "0x1", "Type":"MapPoint",  "X": 2, "Y": 3}
float x = a.X;
```

Comment: `{ "Version":  "0x1", "Type":"MapPoint",  "X": 2, "Y": 3} ` 
is the text I code to a QR code. 

But I get its content  then which is equal to:
`" { \"Version \":  0x1, \"Type \": \"MapPoint \",  \"X \": 2, \"Y \": 3} "`